# Data type problems with getElementById (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba, getelementbyid

I am trying to scrape some text from a webpage into Excel.

I think the code below brings it into an object property called output, but I need to end up with a string.

I have tried using CType to convert the property into a string, but whatever I do I get a syntax error.

I have also tried using getElementById(id).innerText - based on what I read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_innertext.a), that would still return a property, but actually I get a type mismatch if I use it with output defined as a property. If I define output as a string, the code compiles OK, but when it runs I get “Object variable or With block variable not set”.

How do I get the text content of the element as a string?

```
Sub Scrape()

Dim ie As Object
Dim cr As String
Dim li As String
Dim lien As String
Dim cnd As String
Dim doc As New HTMLDocument
Dim id As String
Dim output As Property

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

cr = Cells(1, 1)
li = Cells(1, 2)
lien = URLEncode(li)
cnd = Cells(1, 3)
id = Cells(2, 1)

With ie

    .Visible = True
    .Navigate (cr & lien & cnd)

    Do
       DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    Set doc = ie.document

    Set output = doc.getElementById(id) '<< Can't extract text from this property
End With

End Sub
```

sp

Comment: `Dim output As Object` should work.  FYI there's no `CType` in VBA

Comment: Thanks. It runs OK and I guess the text I want ends up in the object, but I still can't figure out how to get it out as text. I get *Object doesn't support this property or method*  whenever I try to assign the object as the value of a string or Excel cell. Noted about CType - I guess I need some kind of get text from object command.

Comment: What type of element is it?

Comment: If I've got the right one it's just text, but maybe the problem is that I haven't. Is there any way to view the content / properties?

Comment: You can put a Watch on `output`

Comment: Value <Out of context>, Type Empty. Switched to getElementsByClassName, no change. Obviously missing something basic. The content of a tag that starts <span class="meaning"> should be picked up by getElementsByClassName("meaning"), right?

Comment: Yes but remember  `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection. not a single element, so you need to look at (eg) `output(0)` not just `output`

Comment: Can you share the url and the value of id you are using when fails?

Comment: I have it working now with getElementsByClassName - many thanks.